# Connect-PnPOnline : The 'Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the module 'SharePointPnPPowerShell2013', but the module could not be loaded.

Tags: pnp-powershell

I have installed PnP Powershell and I tried to run `Connect-PnPOnline`, but I got the following error:

```
Connect-PnPOnline : The 'Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the module 'SharePointPnPPowerShell2013', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://test.rod.com/sites/Projects"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-PnPOnline:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

So, I run "`Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013`" as the error suggests, then I get another error:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'SharePointPnPPowerShell2013' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SharePointPnPPowerShell2013:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I followed the instructions as stated in [github repo](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell), but still did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [github post](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1447). It worked for him.

He installed the [SharePoint 2013 Client SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) and apparently it worked.